# Windows Thinkpad wont display screen on laptop but does on monitors

Tags: display, windows-11

A week ago I upgraded from Windows 10 to Windows 11. Everything has been fine thus far. I just plugged my PC into my dock and opened it up, my monitors diasplay as normal, but my laptop screen is black. In display settings, my two monitors are detected, but the laptop screen is not detected as a display at all. I shut down the PC and disconnected my laptop, rebooted, and the screen light up black but did not display anything. I plugged it back into my dock and my monitors kicked on as before but the laptop screen went dark again.

Sys info

- Windows 11 (recent upgrade from 10)
- Lenova T495
- AMD Ryzen Pro

Let me know if there is anymore info I can provide or a better exchange to ask my question... there doesn't seem to be a place like "Ask Ubuntu" for windows.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Update BIOS (UEFI), Chipset, and Video Drivers.  Use Lenovo System Update to do this. Restart and test.

Comment: Followed your advice. Lenova System Update returned no applicable packages found